# I cannot connect to Steam; `-tcp` option partially helps

Tags: windows-10, tcp, steam

Since last night I have not been able to connect to Steam with my main account, I would just get a screen that says

> Unable to connect to Steam

unless I add `-tcp` to the shortcut, then I can at least log into Steam, however I can't connect to any game servers that use Steam servers.

I can also log in manually by typing in my info, but it normally takes three attempts:

1. The client just refreshes.
2. I get the "cannot connect to Steam" error.
3. It loads into Steam, but again I'm unable to connect to any game servers that use Steam servers (Valve games, Tripwire Interactive games, etc.).

I've spent the last 6 hours googling fixes, and so far have come up with nothing being able to work. I figured before taking a break, I'd see if anyone had any ideas I hadn't tried yet. So far I've done as follows:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled Steam.
- Cleared local temp files, reset PC, no change.
- Uninstalled, reinstalled wireless drivers, reset PC, no change.
- Ran about 7 different commands in CMD relating to `winsock` and `netsh`, reset PC, no change.
- Logged into a different account without `-tcp` (still unable to connect to game servers).
- Deleted `ClientRegistry.blob`, no change.
- Reset my router, no change.

I might be forgetting a couple other things I've tried. I've spent way to long at the PC and need a break, really hoping anyone can help me sort this out.

Comment: Have you tried disabling IPv6 inside of the Network Settings?  I had an issue similar to this, and I fixed it by disabling IPv6 so that IPv4 was the default (and only) connection.

Comment: Can  you visit any website, if so tcp probably isn't the issue.  Blocking tcp would effective cut you off from the internet as 95+% of everything uses tcp.  Did you try changing steam servers?

Comment: @cybernard No problem connecting to the internet, the issue seems to only be related to steam and games that use their servers, I have access to the client and can use and connect to any game online so long as said game has their own dedicated servers, but if its a game that uses steam servers, the server list is blank, despite saying "x" amount of people online. Worth bringing up, if I have a friend who is playing said game, I can join off them, but I am unable to play alone.

Comment: @FoxMcloud5655 Tried it out, but no changes.

Comment: The `-tcp` option forces Steam to use TCP instead of UDP. UDP is commonly used for online gaming ([read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5330277)). It seems the problem is with UDP, but since you can join non-Steam servers, not all UDP traffic ([ports](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711), [source/destination](http://bgp.he.net/AS32590#_prefixes)) is affected. As if somebody put a dedicated packet filter between you and the Internet. You're not a teenager whose parents like to play with parental control on their advanced home router, are you?

Answer (score 0):

When exactly the same happened to me, after wasting a lot of time doing similar things to the above - I eventually created a new administrative account, moved my profile over - not registry, only Documents, photos etc- and I hard-reset my router - not restoring from backup but just doing the basics. (some firewall rules, ssid/wpa2 etc)

It took me 30 mins - and now steam works fine. Once you are happy delete the old user profile.